# C# Bubble sorting Linked List for loop question

Tags: c#

```
  public void BubbleSortExData()
    {
        Node end = null;
        Node p = null;
        Node q = null;

        for (end = null ; end != start.link; end = p)
        {
            for (p = start; p.link != end; p = p.link)
            {
                q = p.link;

                if (p.data > q.data)
                {
                    int temp = p.data;
                    p.data = q.data;
                    q.data = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I have this code, and it's working fine, but I am having hard time understanding it.

I get the part where we compare two int values, and we replace them if needed. But I don't understand  two for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As you say, the `if` statement swaps the data of 2 nodes if they are out of order.
- The inner loop applies this `if` to each node from the beginning (`start`) until `end`, in that order.  This means that the largest value will now be at the `end`.
- The outer loop applies this process to successive `end`s, working from back to front.  This means that with each iteration, the sorted portion of the list is a longer suffix of the it, until it covers the whole list.

Comment: Thanks for answering Scott !! ... So in outer loop , what does this last par mean end = p 

How will end change ? what will it become in second go of outer loop?

Comment: `end` gets assigned the value of `p` after the inner loop ends.

Comment: Does that mean that outer loop is triggered only 2 times?

Comment: No; it keeps going until the end is the start.

Comment: Hey Scott, any chance u know what would be BigO notation for this algorithm?